# How to get OTHER users' photos and albums with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Scenario: logged with my Facebook account and using a browser, I'm able to see some photos and albums of some users which aren't friends of mine (with a privacy setting of public or similar) and quite all their past profile photos.
For example the URL

`https://www.facebook.com/<userid>/photos_all` shows those photos.

I want to replicate behaviour with Graph API but GETting

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<userid>/photos?access_token=...
```

Gives me an empty `data` array.

Same scenario using `tagged` or `albums` instead of `photos`

I've tried to use site scraping but FB website uses AJAX to populate gridview of photos, so It's very difficult.

On Graph API Explorer I've requested and use an access token with all permissions and also a debug access token but I'm still unable to get other users' photos.

It's possibile to get photos of users which aren't in friend list with Facebook Graph API? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

For privacy reasons, it´s not possible to get the photos of OTHER users with the API. Even for the authorized user, you need the `user_photos` permission.

Scraping is not allowed btw: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Even if the photo has public privacy setting? Quoting from Graph API Reference 'Any valid access token for any photo with public privacy settings'

Comment: i believe that goes only for page photos, but for user photos you still need to authorize a user.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos say: "A user access token with user_photos permission is required to see all photos that person is tagged in or has uploaded". And I can't see anything there saying you can use any access token. What documentation are you reading?

Comment: @WizKid , you're right. I've read [photo reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo/).